# Using MapThread on list of lists

Tags: list-manipulation

Just a light weight question for learning. If you think this was asked before, please feel free to close it.

I am trying to learn `MapThread` more, and wanted to use it to generate `Rule` from a list  like this

```
lst = {{1, 2},{a, b}}
```

in order to obtain

```
(* {1 -> a, 2 -> b}  *)
```

Using `MapThread` works nice:

```
MapThread[Rule, lst]
(* {1 -> a, 2 -> b}  *)
```

But when the list contain more than one list in it, like this

```
lst = {{{1, 2}, {a, b}}, {{3, 4}, {c, d}}}
```

Then I could not find a way to use `MapThread` on its own on the whole list. It needs help to iterate over all the lists. So what I do now is `Map` the function `MapThread` on each list in the list. Like this

```
Map[ MapThread[Rule, #] &,  lst]
(*  {{1 -> a, 2 -> b}, {3 -> c, 4 -> d}}  *)
```

I did not want to do this:

```
MapThread[Rule, ArrayFlatten[{lst}]]
(* {1 -> a, 2 -> b, 3 -> c, 4 -> d} *)
```

because it loses the structure I had at the start, even though I can correct things with

```
Partition[%, 2]
(* {{1 -> a, 2 -> b}, {3 -> c, 4 -> d}} *)
```

But it seems not a good way to do it.

Question is: What is the recommended way to do this type of operation? Can `MapThread` be told to do this on its own without the help of `Map`?  Are there other commands to do the above that you think are better?

I used `Rule` above, but you can replace that with any function `f` that takes 2 arguments.

**Update 12/26/12**

Fyi, I made a small addition to the solution so that it can be also used for 2D matrix, in addition to the 3D matrix (since this was not part of what I was asking originally).

Here is my changes. I found that the trick is to tell `Apply` the level to use. For 2D matrix, use level 0 or {}. But for 3D matrix, use {1}. This assumes the input is either 2D or 3D.

So this is how it looks now:

```
f[lst_List] :=Apply[Thread[Rule[#1, #2]] &, lst,If[MatrixQ[lst], Sequence @@ {}, {1}]]
f[ {{1, 2}, {a, b}} ]
(* {1 -> a, 2 -> b} *)
```

and

```
f[ {{{1, 2}, {a, b}}, {{3, 4}, {c, d}}}]
(*  {{1 -> a, 2 -> b}, {3 -> c, 4 -> d}} *)
```

Another way I could have done this, is by making 2 function definitions

```
f[lst_?(MatrixQ[#] &)] := Apply[Thread[Rule[#1, #2]] &, lst]
f[lst_List] := Apply[Thread[Rule[#1, #2]] &, lst, {1}]
```

But I personally never liked this type of coding much. Because now the logic is spread around, instead of all being contained in one place that is easier to see and maintain, So I normally like to have one function, and inside it, add the different logic needs for different values and types of the input, rather than define many different functions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yet another way would be this:

```
Thread[#1 -> #2] & @@@ lst
```

Answer (score 14):

```
lst = {{{1, 2}, {a, b}}, {{3, 5}, {4, f}}}
```

You could also do

```
MapThread[Rule, lst\[Transpose] , 2]
(* {{1 -> a, 2 -> b}, {3 -> 4, 5 -> f}} *)
```

Answer (score 9):

Another alternative is:

```
Thread /@ (Rule @@@ lst)
```

Answer (score 8):

Since `V 13.1` there is `MapApply`

```
lst = {{{1, 2}, {a, b}}, {{3, 4}, {c, d}}};
```

Correct version (thanks to @kglr):

```
MapApply[Thread @* Rule] @ lst
```

{{1 -> a, 2 -> b}, {3 -> c, 4 -> d}}

Comment: you probably meant `MapApply[Thread@*Rule]@lst`?

Comment: Yes, corrected, thank you very much

Answer (score 6):

```
 Inner[Rule, Sequence @@ #, List] & /@ lst
 Apply[Rule, Transpose /@ lst, {2}]
 Apply[Rule, Thread /@ lst, {2}]
 (* {{1 -> a, 2 -> b}, {3 -> c, 4 -> d}} *)
```

where

```
 lst = {{{1, 2}, {a, b}}, {{3, 4}, {c, d}}}
```

EDIT: For inputs with different depths:

```
  thrdRlF = Apply[Rule, Thread /@ #, {Depth[#] - 2}] &
  thrdRlF[lst]
  (* {{1 -> a, 2 -> b}, {3 -> c, 4 -> d}} *)
  thrdRlF[lst[[1]]]
  (* {1 -> a, 2 -> b} *)
  thrdRlF[lst[[1,1]]]
  (* 1 -> 2 *)
  thrdRlF[lst[[1,1,1]]]
  (* 1 *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `Cases`:

```
lst = {{{1, 2}, {a, b}}, {{3, 4}, {c, d}}};

Cases[lst, {x : {__}, y : {__}} :> Rule @@@ {x, y}]

(*{{1 -> 2, a -> b}, {3 -> 4, c -> d}}*)
```

Also, combining `Cases` with `MapThread`:

```
Cases[lst, x : {__} :> MapThread[Rule, Transpose@x]]

(*{{1 -> 2, a -> b}, {3 -> 4, c -> d}}*)
```

Or using `ReplaceAll`:

```
lst /. x : {__} /; VectorQ[x] :> Rule @@ x

(*{{1 -> 2, a -> b}, {3 -> 4, c -> d}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

All the normal looking answers have been given.

Given a list

```
lst = {{{1, 2}, {a, b}}, {{3, 4}, {c, d}}};
```

we can use

```
ArrayReshape[
 Inner[Rule, Select[lst // Flatten, Head[#] == Integer &], 
  Transpose@Variables[lst // Flatten], List], {Length@lst, 
  Length@lst}]
```